# plot map chart of dataset by Python

Tags: python, plot, charts, data-visualization, datavisualization.toolkit

I have a csv file that a column of that is location. the locations are from all regions of the world but only the states of America are important for us. The screenshot of the dataset is the following:[image]

How can I plot a map chart like the following by the python?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make a Choropleth graph. I can think of Choropleth in Plotly. The link is https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/. If you do not have a shape file or GeoJson for it, you can use the code in section "Using Built-in Country and State Geometries" then you would not need shape file or these geometry objects. Also, later if you want to do some interaction in Dash, you can use this graph as one of your graphs in Dash.

Answer (score 1):

Get [shape files for the US states](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html) and then you can plot a [choropleth map with geopandas](https://geopandas.org/mapping.html).